# SQL insert dot or comma into varchar (accounting, money)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, type-conversion

I'm currently sitting on a MySQL-table that has column called unitprice (VARCHAR) formatted as follows;

**Example** 
 
5102938 
304948 
495845

The data represents money; the last two numbers are always cents.

**Result** 
51029.38 
3049.48 
4958.45

My goal is to insert a dot on the third-final position so I can use CAST/CONVERT to convert the column from VARCHAR to DECIMAL. Does MySQL have regex support which may allow me to do this? Or any build-in features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert to unsigned and divide by 100:

```
select cast(unitprice as unsigned) / 100.0
```

If the values are really big, you might need something bigger than `unsigned`, but it is a reasonable choice for most currencies and prices.

Of course, if you want it as a decimal, then use that:

```
select cast(unitprice as decimal(10, 2)) / 100.0
```

Be sure to put in the precision and scale that are appropriate for your problem.

Comment: `CAST(12345670/100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)): 123456.70` versus
            `FORMAT(12345670/100, 2): 123,456.70`